# Android View Visibility GONE

Tags: android

If i set a views visibility which as been inflated, to gone, will it Speed up my UI?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It will speed up the actual drawing of the UI, because, well, you don't have to draw it anymore, but it will still be inflated and the inflation process will not be faster.

Comment: I wonder if a view with visibility GONE is still taking part in the layouting process? i.e., does it measure its size and stuff? That would make it different from a ViewStub.

Comment: A GONE View is always ignored during layout.

Comment: @Matthias Only VISIBLE and INVISIBLE views participate in measuring/layout, not GONE views. ViewStubs are advantageous in some situations not because they skip the measuring/layout (which a normal `include` would do if it was set to GONE), but because they postpone the actual inflation of the contents into Views. This is useful for rarely-shown layouts like empty-list views or error messages since it saves memory/time on the View object allocations and XML processing.

Comment: What to do if I only want to show the layout in the AS editor but not the actual runtime layout without incurring any cost?

Answer (score 1):

GONE = This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.