# Is a view set to View.GONE still on the view stack?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-view

Im am trying to clean up my view hirarchy in order to prevent stackoverflow errors.

If I set a view's visibility to `View.GONE`, will this remove the view from the view stack?

Comment: *will this remove the view from the view stack?* - what exactly do you mean? The view will not participate in the measuring/layout phases(so those will improve) but it will still occupy memory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android View Visibility GONE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392842/android-view-visibility-gone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View.GONE**

This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

**View.INVISIBLE**

This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

**View.VISIBLE**

This view is visible, and takes up space for layout purposes.

**Note:-** All above views will occupy memory

Comment: But not all events will fire like onMeasure in case of GONE